# Android: Blur out screen on clicking a button

Tags: android

I have been trying hard to find a solution to this problem.
I have an activity with number of buttons and layouts and a set of buttons, say btnA, btnB, btnC. Now on clicking btnA, I want to defocus or blur out the whole screen, except that set of buttons, btnA, btnB, btnC. Is it possible ?

I tried to change the alpha value of all layouts, but its not working.

Comment: Have you tried some thing. please post some code.

Answer (score 1):

[Integrate the RenderScript Support Library](https://futurestud.io/blog/how-to-use-the-renderscript-support-library-with-gradle-based-android-projects/)

Then add this class to blur out the required image.

```
public class BlurBuilder {
private static final float BITMAP_SCALE = 0.4f;
private static final float BLUR_RADIUS = 7.5f;

public static Bitmap blur(Context context, Bitmap image) {
    int width = Math.round(image.getWidth() * BITMAP_SCALE);
    int height = Math.round(image.getHeight() * BITMAP_SCALE);

    Bitmap inputBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, width, height, false);
    Bitmap outputBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(inputBitmap);

    RenderScript rs = RenderScript.create(context);
    ScriptIntrinsicBlur theIntrinsic = ScriptIntrinsicBlur.create(rs, Element.U8_4(rs));
    Allocation tmpIn = Allocation.createFromBitmap(rs, inputBitmap);
    Allocation tmpOut = Allocation.createFromBitmap(rs, outputBitmap);
    theIntrinsic.setRadius(BLUR_RADIUS);
    theIntrinsic.setInput(tmpIn);
    theIntrinsic.forEach(tmpOut);
    tmpOut.copyTo(outputBitmap);

    return outputBitmap;
}}
```

Then add this code to your btnA's clickListner and pass your image to it.

```
   Bitmap blurredBitmap = BlurBuilder.blur( getActivity(), originalBitmap );
   view.setBackgroundDrawable( new BitmapDrawable( getResources(), blurredBitmap ) );
```